# Dynamic variable SetEnv vhost Ubuntu Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, setenv

I apologize if this question has already been asked.

I am looking for a solution to make `SetEnv` use the %2 variable.

Is that even possible?

My vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.someuri.nl
        ServerAlias *.*.dev.someuri.nl
        VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%2/www/%1
        LogLevel debug

        SetEnv DEVELOP_ENV dev
        SetEnv DEVELOP_NAME %2
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to my problem using `SetEnvIf`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.someuri.nl
        ServerAlias *.*.dev.someuri.nl
        VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%2/www/%1
        LogLevel debug
        SetEnv DEVELOP_ENV dev
        SetEnvIf Host "^(.*)\.(.*)\.dev\.someuri.nl" DEVELOP_NAME=$2
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope it helps people googling themselves silly.